# GA4-API - Can't get data prior to when an included Custom Definition was created

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

Whenever I add a custom dimension or metric, the fetched data begin from the date when that most recent dimension/metric was registered, even if the start date is set to before that.

And what is weird is that it's from not the registering point, but it's from its date. I've made the following test:

- Fetched Event Count by Date
- Fetched Event Count by Date and a New Dimension (which was created in the middle of the 8th).

Both fetches were with Start Date as May 1st. The second only showed data from the 8th, but the total Event Count for both was the same in the 8th and 9th.

So it's not like the data from the second test is being fetched from the point of the dimension registering, or it would have a lower Event Count on the 8th. It's like it's redefining the Start Date to be same as the registering date of the new Dimension.

I tested in both the GA4 Magic Reports and SyncWith addons for Google Spreadsheets and got the same results.

Is this supposed to be the standard behavior? If not, any ideas on how to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: please edit your question and include [example]